# What is the difference between fixed format languages and free format languages?

Tags: syntax, programming-languages

While studying the principles of programming languages, I have seen that we can categorise programming languages as "free format" or "fixed format". For example, Java and C are free format languages, whereas RPG is a fixed format language. But I don't know what are the meanings of these two terms, or how tell which category a given language is in. I have searched on Google and am unable to get a meaningful idea.

This is mentioned in my lecture slide:

> ```
> int  a = 0
> ```
>
> In Java and C, this interpretation  is based on syntax. These kind of languages are called as **free format**. But in RPG, this semantic is based on how we take these different components with the layout. These kind of languages are called as **fixed format**.

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-form_language

Comment: @kaya3 I think so, but not sure.Explanation is not clear. This difference is mentioned in my lecture slide as "When given int a = 0, this interpretation is based on syntax in Java and C. But in RPG, this symentic is based on ow we take these different components with the layout".

Comment: Please edit the question to include the relevant part of the lecture slides which you don't understand. Be careful to copy it accurately.

Comment: @kaya3 I edited it.

Comment: Are you sure that the lecture slides say "symentic"? This is a spelling error, and seems to be a grammatical error too.

Comment: Yes. I think symentic should be corrected as semantic. I edited it.

Comment: There don't seem to be many useful sources for answering this question; I was able to find about one page from a textbook on Google Books. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1fPSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=fixed-form+syntax+programming+language&source=bl&ots=u4bO69NK7E&sig=ACfU3U3QJISs2l-5TGXMVrBpo9ZP12VROw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDzN61lK_mAhUWiFwKHQFCD8IQ6AEwDHoECA4QAQ#v=onepage&q=fixed-form%20syntax%20programming%20language&f=false

Answer (score 4):

Most languages these days are 'free format' since we program on interactive devices.

Back when programs were punched on to cards, it was common for there to be requirements to punch certain things in certain columns.

For example, FORTRAN circa 1966:

Column 1 - 'C' for comment
Columns 2 to 5 (maybe 1 to 5, I forget) - numeric statement label
Column 6 - if non-blank, denotes continuation of previous statement
Columns 7 to 71 - the statement
Column 72 to 80 - optional sequence number (not interpreted by FORTRAN)

COBOL had similar rules.

Some assembly languages (ICL 1900 PLAN for example) also had column-use restrictions.

RPG as far as I recall had even stricter rules about what got punched where.  For example, a single character in column 6 indicated the data type of some object.

It was often the case that fixed-format programming languages were written on paper forms designed for the specific language, with were pre-printed with column usage. The programmer wrote by hand and then handed over to professional card-punch operators to be punched up.

Fixed-format tended to be adopted by languages developed on systems that saw punched cards as the main form of input.  Paper-tape based systems tended towards free-form input.

These days, though, fixed-format is mostly a thing of the past, and it is the syntax of statement elements, rather than their position, that determines meaning.

(See [pages 7 and 8 in this FORTRAN II manual](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/fortran/F28-8074-3_FORTRANII_GenInf.pdf))

(For RPG II, see [page 12 in this manual](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/system34/SC21-7667-4_System_34_RPG_II_Reference_Manual_Jan82.pdf) for IBM System 34.

Comment: Thank you great explanation.